# Changing default 403 forbidden message

Tags: permissions, apache2

I'm using Virtualmin as the control panel for my ubuntu server. Every time i create a new virtual server, when i visit the site it says

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

That happens because i haven't uploaded any file to the server.

I'd like to ask how to customize that forbidden message. For example, i want to put a sentence to ask users to upload files to the server, something like:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server. If you have recently created a new account, please go ahead and upload your files to server. Thanks!
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'ErrorDocument' directive in Apache.  You can place the code in either your global (server) config, or each virtualhost.

For example...

```
ErrorDocument 403 "You don't have permission to access / on this server. If you have recently created a new account, please go ahead and upload your files to server. Thanks!"
```